# What file formats can openXML save?

Tags: openxml, document

Looking at the openXML SDK 2.5 page [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278315(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278315%28v=office.15%29.aspx) I can't see where it specifies what document formats it can create, where would I find this on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenXml SDK 2.5 supports saving the following Microsoft Office files:

Word (.docx)

Excel (.xlsx)

PowerPoint (.pptx)

It further supports document files in both conformance clauses, "transitional" and "strict".

"Strict" files can be read by Microsoft Office since Office 2010 and they can be created by Microsoft Office 2013 (and later).

But in the end - since you are manipulating the raw Xml-code in the files, using the SDK, you can basically do anything you like ... and screw things up as much as you like.

:-)